# How to serve VueJS 3 app from subfolders in NGINX?

Tags: vue.js, nginx

I want to serve multiple VueJS 3 apps from same NGINX server but from different subfolders. I've stumbled upon and tried myriad resource from stack and web but things are not coming together.

I have three apps and three build types.

production: mydomain.com/app1, mydomain.com/app2, mydomain.com/app3

staging: mydomain.com/staging/app1, mydomain.com/staging/app2, mydomain.com/staging/app3

dev: mydomain.com/dev/app1, mydomain.com/dev/app2, mydomain.com/dev/app3

I've tried modifying the vue.config.js, router/index.js and NGINX configuration but nothing seems to click.

I'll sincerely appreciate if someone can share a comprehensive guide to my issue.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

**try this conf**

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    # SSL configuration
    #
    #listen 443 ssl;
    #listen [::]:443 ssl;
    
    #ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/your-domain/fullchain.pem;
    #ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/your-domain/privkey.pem;
    
    #
    #ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/live/dhparam/dhparam.pem;

    #ssl_protocols TLSv1.2;

    #ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    #ssl_ciphers 'ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA';  
    #add_header X-Frame-Options DENY;

    root /var/www/proyect-vue/dist;

    # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
        index index.html index.htm index.php;

    server_name your-domain;

    location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }

 
    # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
    # concurs with nginx's one
    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

and now, you can clone repository in **/var/www/** with git and type **npm run build**

Comment: Thanks @elvis-roman, but I am not clear. I am using NGINX as reverse-proxy. I want to define three locations pointing to three separate Vue.js apps. e.g. location /app1 {} location /app2 {} and so on. I just can't get it working. I think there is some change required in the vue app configuration as well. Thanks. Let me know.